# How can I get an index from an JOptionPane menu

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm trying to get the index of what the user chooses so that I can call the class object with the number from the drop-down menu.

```java
String[] storeListArr;
Object storePick;
ArrayList<String> storeList = new ArrayList<>();

while (!(newStore[nCount] == null)) {
    storeList.add(newStore[nCount].getName());
    nCount++;
} //end loop

storeListArr = new String[storeList.size()];
storePick = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose Store", "Store Selection", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, storeListArr, storeListArr[0]);
```

So if the user picks newStore1 from the drop-down menu, I can call the store class and get whatever I want from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to get the index of what the user chooses

The `showInputDialog(...)` only returns the String that was selected.

If you want to know the index then you need to use methods of the `ArrayList`:

```
storePick = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
int index = storeList.indexOf( storePick );
```